# How does cache partitioning prevent covert/side-channel attacks?

Tags: memory, caching, side-channel, covert-channel

In a report on an open-source separation kernel ([Muen kernel](https://muen.codelabs.ch/muen-report.pdf)) I was reading, in the future work section, it says that cache coloring can be implemented to prevent covert/side-channel attacks.

It is mentioned that

> In a second step each subject is associated with a color. All subjects of a given color share the same cache partition. In turn subjects of differing color have no access to identical cache locations, which means the cache cannot be used as a side-channel.

I understand what page coloring/cache partitioning is, but I do not understand how having different subjects use different cache partitions can solve side-channel attacks. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/94036/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.